# Img src for svg file doesn't work if property binding is used in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, dom, angular8

I have an array in my component

```js
    this.myArray = [
      {
        img: '/path/to/myImage.svg',
        title: 'My Image'
      }
    ]
```

Which I am using in the template to render a list

```html
    <div *ngFor="let item of myArray">
        <img src="/path/to/myImage.svg"> --> This works
        <img [src]="item.img"> --> this gives error 404
    <div>
```

I am able to show the svg if I directly provide the url, however, property binding throws 404 error, What am I missing here?

P.S my angular project doesn't include angular-cli/angular.json

Answer (score 1):

I think if you are receiving data asynchronous then your binding should be work.
When the value is received, AsyncPipe signals the component to check for changes.
https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

```
images$: Observable<Image[]> = this.imageService.getImage();

<div *ngFor="let image of images$ | async">
   <img [src]="image.src"/>
<div>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, String interpolation is used to display dynamic data on HTML template (at user end). It facilitates you to make changes on component.ts file and fetch data from there to HTML template (component.html file).

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray">

  <img src="{{item.img}}"> 
<div>
```

Comment: Can you share your project structure

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myArray">
    <div *ngFor="let item of myArray">
        <img src="/path/to/myImage.svg"> --> This works
        <img [attr.src]="item.img"> --> this should work
    <div>
</ng-container>
```